# Difficulties with complex statistics counting in different groups using Scala Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, window-functions

I tried to struggle with this problem but finally decide to ask for help. I am using Scala Spark. I have DataFrame with several fields, some important ones: id, platform, time, info.

Firstly, I group data by (id, platform) and now I have groups with (time, info, stat).
Column "stat" here is replacement for several columns, so stat = (stat_col_1, stat_col_2, etc..)

Secondly, let's sort it to make it easier to understand. Now we have something like this:

```
Group 1:

time1, info1, stat1 |
time2, info2, stat2 |
time3, info3, stat3 |
time4, info4, stat4 |
time5, info5, stat5 V sorted ascending by time

Group 2:

time1, info1, stat1 |
time2, info2, stat2 |
time3, info3, stat3 V sorted ascending by time

etc.
```

I know, that there is some cells in "info" column with value "START". I want to split it at session by different "START"s and count some statistic (many columns) with stat. So now we have:

```
Ex.: (Some infos from previous example changed to START)

Group 1:

time1, START, stat1 | 
time2, info2, stat2 |  <-- count columns A, B, using "stat" columns (stat_col_1, etc..)
time3, info3, stat3 |
--------- split here -------
time4, START, stat4 |  <-- same here
time5, info5, stat5 V sorted ascending by time
```

After that we get some sort fo data:

For every (id, platform) we get statistics for all their session, that we extracted using value "START" at info column, sorted in ascending order by time.

Now I want to concat all this data to single DataFrame.

I have a solution, where from initial DataFrame I get all unique (id, platform) data, and then, using for-loop, I split data by START event and count stat iteratively going by every row in small groups. It is kinda slow because honestly it does not use any spark facilities (because now I do all just using for loops). I feel that there should be solution using Window functions but I do not know really, help me please.